# SAS Error: "No logical assign for filename SALARIES"

Tags: sas, filenames

I am running SAS Studio 3.6 Basic Edition. I am a beginner at SAS and I can't get past this error that I've been having. I have the code below and the file is in the correct place. I created a folder under the "my folders" in the sidebar called "Exercises" and under that I created a folder called "data". It seems that it is not reading the file but I'm not sure why because the path is correct (to my knowledge).

Any ideas? I have already tried googling and most of the results with this error have to do with _WEBOUT which I don't believe is my problem.

```
DATA SALARIES;
INFILE '/Exercises/data/AAUP_data.txt';
INFILE SALARIES delimiter=',';
INPUT FICE College_Name $ State $ Type $ Average_Salary_Full
Average_Salary_Assoc Average_Salary_Asst Average_Salary_All
Average_Comp_Full Average_Comp_Assoc Average_Comp_Asst Average_Comp_All
Number_of_Professors_Full Number_of_Professors_Assoc
Number_of_Professors_Asst Number_of_Instructors Number_of_Faculty_All
;
RUN;
PROC PRINT;
RUN;
```

I appreciate the help.

Comment: Are you using SAS UE?

Comment: Yes I am. I downloaded it from my university.

Comment: From SAS Analytics U, or from your university? This doesn't look like a full path?

Answer (score 0):

Your second `infile` statement is meant to be used in conjunction with a `filename` statement.

If your `SALARIES` infile is meant to be the text file stored at `'/Exercises/data/AAUP_data.txt'`, then there are two ways you could write this:

```
FILENAME SALARIES '/Exercises/data/AAUP_data.txt';
DATA SALARIES;
INFILE SALARIES delimiter=',';
INPUT FICE College_Name $ State $ Type $ Average_Salary_Full
Average_Salary_Assoc Average_Salary_Asst Average_Salary_All
Average_Comp_Full Average_Comp_Assoc Average_Comp_Asst Average_Comp_All
Number_of_Professors_Full Number_of_Professors_Assoc
Number_of_Professors_Asst Number_of_Instructors Number_of_Faculty_All
;
RUN;
PROC PRINT;
RUN;
```

or simply

```
DATA SALARIES;
INFILE '/Exercises/data/AAUP_data.txt' delimiter=',';
INPUT FICE College_Name $ State $ Type $ Average_Salary_Full
Average_Salary_Assoc Average_Salary_Asst Average_Salary_All
Average_Comp_Full Average_Comp_Assoc Average_Comp_Asst Average_Comp_All
Number_of_Professors_Full Number_of_Professors_Assoc
Number_of_Professors_Asst Number_of_Instructors Number_of_Faculty_All
;
RUN;
PROC PRINT;
RUN;
```

Comment: So it is throwing an error because I have two INFILE statements? I thought this was allowed?

Comment: No, it is throwing an error because the fileref `SALARIES` is unknown to SAS. It must first be initialize, typically using a `FILENAME` statement like in my first example.